# Existence of Saddle Point

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $g$ with the following properties.

- It is smooth.
- $g > 0$.
- $g \to 0$ at infinity.
- It has at least two critical points.
- There are finitely many critical points.
- Each critical point is isolated.

Thanks to the [answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105424/7998), I am going to add one additional restriction on $g$.

- $g$ is a rational function.

I am adding yet another condition after seeing an edit below.

- Each critical point of $g$ is non-degenerate; that is, if $x$ is a critical point then $\det g''(x) \neq 0$.

In the [example below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105424/7998), the critical point that is not a saddle has a zero eigenvalue and hence the determinant is zero.

Notice at least one of the critical points has to be a local max.

The question is: does $g$ have a saddle point?

In particular, for $g \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, does $g$ have a critical point of index $n-1$?

If there is a reference you can point me to that would be terrific. I believe a variant of the Mountain Pass Theorem may work...

Comment: Where does your function $g$ live? When you write "in particular, for $g:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$", which other environments are you envisaging?

Comment: I am just interested in real functions in $n$ independent variables.

Answer (score 4):

Consider functions of the form
$$
g(x,y,a)=a e^{-((x-1)^2+y^2)}+e^{-((x+1)^2+y^2)}
$$
where $a\geq 1$. For suitable value of $a$ you can get exactly to critical points. One of them will point of maximum, another just a critical point. Necessary condition for $a$ is 
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0,0,a)=0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,0,a)\geq0\quad\text{ for all } x\text{ in the neighborhood of }x_0 
$$
Here is a graph of such a function. Approximately $a\approx 3$.
[image]

If we make an additional requirement that functions are rational the answer is still no. Indeed consider function of the form
$$
g(x,y,a)=\frac{a}{(x-1)^2+y^2+1}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+y^2+1}
$$
where $a\geq 1$. For the appropriate value of $a$ you still get one point of maximum, one critical point and no saddle points. This value is approximately equal to $a\approx 2.39$
[image]

Comment: Terrific! That answers my original question. I'm going to make an edit and add one more restriction to $g$ to eliminate this case.

Comment: @James: [Just replace the Gaussian bumps in Norbert's answer with $1/(x^2+y^2+1)$ bumps.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202.4/%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2by%5E2%2b1%29%20%2b%201/%28%28x%2b1%29%5E2%2by%5E2%2b1%29%20for%20x=-3..3,%20y=-3..3)

Comment: Is there a condition I can add to make sure this example will not happen?

Comment: I don't think so. If can make an effective condition, we can describe all saddle points.

Comment: I realized that if I add one more condition then this example will not hold. I made the change above.

Comment: Too complicated, worth a bounty to get more attention to you question

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't satisfy all the conditions of the question, but it's a little too long for a comment. Maybe you'll find it interesting.

Here is an example of a rational function that has two isolated local maxima and no saddle point:
$$g(x,y) = \frac1{(x-1)^2+\big(y-\frac1x\big)^2+1} + \frac1{(x+1)^2+\big(y-\frac1x\big)^2+1}$$
[This is what it looks like.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201/%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2b%28y-1/x%5E2%29%5E2%2b1%29%20%2b%201/%28%28x%2b1%29%5E2%2b%28y-1/x%5E2%29%5E2%2b1%29%20for%20x%20=%20-3..3,%20y%20=%20-2..4) It is just the sum of two "rational bumps", $1/\big((x-1)^2+y^2+1\big)$ and $1/\big((x+1)^2+y^2+1\big)$, composed with a transformation $(x,y) \mapsto \big(x,y-\frac1x\big)$ that sends the saddle point $(0,0)$ to infinity. I first saw this, or something very much like it, on the home page of a math professor who is also an active user on this site, but I can't remember who it was now.

Unfortunately, every point on the line $x = 0$ is also a critical point, which violates a couple of your criteria.

Comment: You can vanish this critical point by summing $g$ with function $s=\arctan(x)\omega(y)$, where $\omega(y)$ is the usual bump function from the theory of distributions. I think you can improve ypur post up to acceptable answer.

Comment: @Norbert: I don't follow. The bump function has compact support, say $[-1,1]$. That still leaves all points of the form $(0,y)$ with $|y| > 1$ as critical points.

Comment: $s$ function vanish critical points on the line $x=0$ and doesn't chhange anything outside domain $\mathbb{R}\times [-1,1]$

Comment: @Norbert, perhaps you mean $s(x,y) = \omega(x) \tan^{-1}(y)$ so that the support of $s$ includes the entire line $x = 0$? In either case, $\tan^{-1}$ does not vanish at infinity, so that would violate another of James's criteria.

Comment: The support of your $s$ function is $[-1,1]\times R$. As for vanishing at infinity, we can conseder $s(x,y)=x e^{-x}\omega(y)$

Comment: @Norbert, I'm afraid we are talking past each other, so I will be more concrete: I don't see how either of your functions removes the critical point $(0, 2)$. If you find a modification that you can prove fulfills all the criteria, please go ahead and post it as a new answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2451/discussion-between-norbert-and-rahul-narain)